How to perform Linux "More" command with a string
I am trying to implement code inside a shell I have made that uses the linux more command to page through a string. I need to be able to use the normal paging controls such as space to go to next page and q to exit and return back to my shell. My current code is this:
        case "more":
            if list[1]==">>"{
                cmd := exec.Command(list[0])
                cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(filesystem.Read(list[2],currentworkingdirectory))
                cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
                err := cmd.Run()
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
            }

This seems to bring up the "more" page but I cannot page through the entries or use any more controls, all I can do is ctrl+c which exits my entire program. list is the console input, I use a redirect >> to indicate that the command should be used on a file within my virtual file system package. filesystem.Read simply returns a very long string at the moment. The entire switch statement is inside of a for loop which should only end when I enter "exit" as a command. list[0] is the current command which is "more" in this case. How can I alter this code to actually use the "more" command correctly with my input string?
Edit: I'm starting to think what I'm trying to do may not be possible but I will leave the question up in case I am wrong. If I have to make a virtual version of this function I am not sure how I would do that either.

Oddly enough, this code works perfectly fine with "less" instead of "more." I would still like to make it work with more though if possible
